# Get 06 number from string how to do

Tags: php, string, numbers

I've a question.
I've a string that can change everytime.

```
  $string = "This is Henk 0612345678";
```

This is a example.
I want to get the 06 number from the string.

So i can use to make a whatsapp api link to whatsapp directly.

Can i do this with preg_replace or is there a easier way?

This is an example i want.

```
 $string = "This is Harry 0645668901";
 $number = "0645668901";
```

If i get the number from the string it has to be converted to:
31645668901 (the zero has to be removed ant 31 has to be added first in the string)

```
 <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=31645668901">Click here</a>
```

If there is no 06 number in the string i dont want to display the link.

Can anyone help me and give me advice ?

Kind regards,
Herman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to remove the words from the string and keep the numbers only.

You can do this.

```
$string = "This is Henk 0612345678";

$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $string);

echo $number;
```

> Output: 0612345678

Then you need to remove the first character which is 0 and add 31 to the beginning of the number so we do this.

```
$number = substr($number, 1) ;
$number = 31 . $number;
```

> Output: 31612345678

And finaly.

```
 <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=<?php echo $number; ?>">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help you sir!) Happy Coding!

Comment: One question, when there are other numbers in the string the preg replace is getting that to. String: or 180 henk 0612345677 the tel number will be 1800612345677 how to fix this?